# How to copy a value from an Excel cell and paste it into a new cell at scale

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to create code that will search for a color value such as "blue" in a cell and if it is found in that cell, paste that value into another cell, and repeat this for a range of a couple hundred colors.

Once that happens, to do the same process again for the next cell down in the column, and pasting into another cell in the corresponding row, until each populated cell has been searched for all color values.

I've got the code to create an Excel sheet that will pull a few predefined values, but I'm not sure how I will expand the code to include hundreds of different colors.

```
#Excel Project to fill attributes quickly.

#Importing Modules
import os, openpyxl

#defining variables
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb['Sheet']

#Asking for your category
x = input('What is your category?')



#Writing header
sheet['A1'] = 'Short Description'
sheet['B1'] = 'Long Description'
sheet['C1'] = 'Item'
sheet['J1'] = 'Color'

#writing attribute values
sheet['A2'] = 'Amazing blue shiny fantastic shirt ee-9003'
sheet['A3'] = 'Red dull jacket'

#Writing values for "Color"

if 'Red' or 'red' in sheet['A2'].value:
    sheet['J2'] = 'Red'
elif 'Orange' or 'orange' in sheet['A2'].value:
    sheet['J2'] = 'Orange'
elif 'Blue' or 'blue' in sheet['A2'].value:
        sheet['J2'] = 'Blue'


if 'Red' or 'red' in sheet['A3'].value:
    sheet['J3'] = 'Red'
elif 'Blue' or 'blue' in sheet['A3'].value:
    sheet['J3'] = 'Blue'


#Saving to your desktop
os.chdir(r'E:\Desktop')
wb.save('Attributes_filled_' + str(x) + '.xlsx')
```

I expect the code to produce "blue" the first time, and "red" the second time for my code so far, but depending on how I order the code, I get the first if statement result.

Comment: You may want to look into `Select case`

Comment: The best solution is create a dictionary of cell values so that you can search this. I've answered this question on Stackoverflow before so you can search for it.

Answer (score 0):

`if 'Red' or 'red' in sheet['A2'].value:` is always considered `True` because non-empty strings are considered `True`.
So in fact it's the same as `if True or 'red' in sheet['A2'].value:`

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object. [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: None and False.
> - zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
> - empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`

any of the following would fix your problem:

```
if 'red' in sheet['A3'].value.lower():
```

or

```
if 'Red' in sheet['A3'].value or 'red' in sheet['A3'].value:
```

or

```
if any(color in sheet['A3'].value for color in ('Red', 'red')):
```

Same apply for all of your if/elif conditions.
Also note that if the string is part of bigger string it will still return True, i.e.
`'Blue" in "I've Got The Blues"` will be evaluated `True`

EDIT: Because of discussion in the comments, I replace evaluate with considered.

Comment: Your explanation isn't quite right. `if "Red" or "red" in …` will always return `"Red"` because as a condition a string is always `True`. More relevant to the question is that conditions in Python must always be explicit ie. the logic should be `if "Red" in cell.value or "red" in cell.value"`

Comment: @CharlieClark, In my answer I don't speak what it will return. I say that the whole condition will be evaluated `True` and thus the respective part of the code will be executed. Of course you are correct that if it is assigned to a variable, it will return 'Red'.

Comment: The whole condition never evaluates because the first part is always true.

Comment: @CharlieClark, I don't want to play semantics, but you are not right. Yes - it will not evaluate further, but the whole condition will be evaluated (considered True) based on the first part - 'Red'. If you are concerned with the use of `evaluate`, read it as `considered`. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: It's really a side issue in any case as it is cell by cell. The solution here is, as I noted above, is to use a dictionary to index the worksheet by cell content.